# Show ticker as floating on webpage in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, floating, ticker

I have a .swf file, which I have to display as a ticker, but the issue is this that I don't want to display it on the webpage, I want it to be floating. Can you please guide me how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.
P.S.; I am using asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the demo](http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/layerfloat.html)
add swf in DIV and make it floating